# Как посмотреть количество удаленных строк в таблице?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Как посмотреть количество удаленных строк в таблице? В идеале и их объем в байтах. 
Ведь записи только помечаются как удаленные. Физически они никуда не деваются до OPTIMIZE TABLE...

Comment: *Как посмотреть количество удаленных строк в таблице?* `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` сразу после удаления. *и их объем в байтах.* А вот это никак.

Comment: так не пойдет. Нужно именно общее количество удаленных строк в таблице, не только за последнюю операцию.

Comment: Ну так получай после каждого запроса да считай сумму. Во проблема... вот только учти - если есть каскадные операции удаления по внешним ключам, они не посчитаются (и я не знаю средства, которое их считает).